# im unable to write output to text file in verilog .Please check what it is wrong

Tags: verilog, fwrite, xilinx, test-bench

```
module fir_tb;

    // Inputs
    reg clk;
    reg reset;
    reg [7:0] inp;
     reg [15:0]rom[1:8001];
    reg [15:0]addr=0;

    // Outputs
    wire [7:0] outp;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    fir uut (
        .clk(clk), 
        .reset(reset), 
        .inp(inp), 
        .outp(outp)
    );




    initial 
  begin
      $readmemb("file_out_flute.txt",rom);
      reset=0;

      inp ='b0;
      #60;

      //$display("rom size is ",rom);
  end
  always @(posedge clk)begin
      inp = rom[addr]>>1;
      addr = addr + 1;
      if (addr==8000) ;//$finish;
  end
       initial 
  begin
      clk=1'b1;
      forever #10 clk=~clk;
  end


    integer f;
  initial begin
   f = $fopen("filter_output.txt","w");
     end

     always @(posedge clk)
     begin
     $fwrite(f,"%b\n",outp);

    $fclose(f);  


  end
endmodule
```

Comment: You are triggering `posedge clk` at the very beginning in `initial` block with this statement `clk=1'b1;`. Change it to `clk=1'b0;` and try again.

Comment: Also improve code indentation and add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$fclose()` closes the file; further writes will be usually be ignored. `$fclose()` is often on of the last operations you you want to call in an simulator; often just before a `$finish` statement.

```
integer f;
initial begin
  f = $fopen("filter_output.txt","w");
  #100; // <== simulation run time
  $fclose(f);
  $finish; // <== end simulation
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
  $fwrite(f,"%b\n",outp);
end
```

Comment: `integer f;
initial begin
  f = $fopen("filter_output.txt","w");
  //#100; // <== simulation run time
  $fclose(f);
  //$finish; // <== end simulation
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
  $fwrite(f,"%b\n",outp);
end`  time should be increased  and finish will end the result soon , it will not allow to compute for some more time

Comment: You can put the `$fclose(f); $finish;` in a different location or change the delay for simulation. The point is once `$fclose` is called, you will not be able to write to the file.